# In Python, how to "point" to an outside object within a class?

Tags: python, class, pointers

In Python, I have a

```
class OBJECT
```

that is initialized. I am now creating a new class that will need to use methods of this object. If I do:

```
class NEW_CLASS:
      def __init__(self, Object):
            self.Object = Object

NEW_CLASS(OBJECT)
```

Does self.Object work like a pointer (excuse the terminology, originally a C programmer) where it points to OBJECT (my desired result) or does self.Object create a separate OBJECT within NEW_CLASS? If it doesn't act like a pointer, how can I implement this behavoir?

I will have one OBJECT in my project but many NEW_CLASS and NEW_CLASS will need to access OBJECT. I don't want to create a new copy for each NEW_CLASS.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unrelated, but it's worth reading the style guide of Python: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ - in particular class names are not all-capitals.

Comment: If you only have one `OBJECT`, why even bother giving a pointer to every instance of `NEW_CLASS` instead of just referencing something global?

Answer (score 2):

It will indeed behave as a pointer. So every time you access `self.Object` you'll be accessing the same `Object` that was initially passed to a new instance of the class `NEW_CLASS`.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want `OBJECT` to be a global object?

How about (stylized to follow Python conventions):

```
class GlobalObject:
    """Insert class definition here."""

OBJECT = GlobalObject()


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, global_object=OBJECT):
        self._object = global_object

    def do_something():
        print "The object is: %s" % self._object
```

Answer (score 0):

No doubt it is the same of object. And they both have the same `id`, meaning memory location in C/C++.

```
>>> id(NEW_CLASS(OBJECT).Object) == id(OBJECT)
True

id(...)
    id(object) -> integer

    Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among
    simultaneously existing objects.  (Hint: it's the object's memory address.)
```

One advice, avoid using `object`(irrespective of cases) as a variable name.

```
help(object)
class object
 |  The most base type
```